# Javascript onClick counter doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I am coding the javascript counter of Like-Hate.

My HTML code is below. (that code is parsed from PHP code)

```
<img id='like1' src='./imoticon/good.png' style='width:23px;height:23px;' title='좋아요' value='1' onclick='onClick(this.value)'>좋아요
<img id='hate1' src='./imoticon/bad.png' style='width:23px;height:23px;' onclick='onClick(this.value)' value='-1' title='싫어요'>싫어요
```

And onClick javascript code is as same .

```
var like_clicks = 0;
var hate_clicks =0;
function onClick(int) {

    like_clicks = like_clicks + document.getElementById("like1").value;
    hate_clicks = hate_clicks + document.getElementById("hate1").value;

    document.getElementById("like1").innerHTML = like_clicks;
    document.getElementById("hate1").innerHTML = hate_clicks;
};
```

But counter doesn't work.
Please help me a piece of advice.

Answer (score 1):

use `this` instead of `this.value` and use `getAttribute` method in javascript

```
<img id='like1' src='./imoticon/good.png' style='width:23px;height:23px;' title='좋아요' value='1' onclick='onClick(this)'/>좋아요
<img id='hate1' src='./imoticon/bad.png' style='width:23px;height:23px;' onclick='onClick(this)' value='-1' title='싫어요'>싫어요/>
```

IN javascript:

```
function onClick(int) {
//alert('click');
console.log(int.getAttribute('value'));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<img id='like1' src='./imoticon/good.png' style='width:23px;height:23px;' title='좋아요' value='1' onclick='onClick(this)'/>좋아요
<img id='hate1' src='./imoticon/bad.png' style='width:23px;height:23px;' onclick='onClick(this)' value='-1' title='싫어요'>싫어요/>




<script>
function onClick(int) {
alert(int.getAttribute('value'));
console.log(int.getAttribute('value'));
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

My HTML code is below

```
.....
<select id="LikeHate">
<option src="./imoticon/good.png" style="background-image:url(like.png);width:23px;height:23px;" onclick="onClick1(this.value)" title="좋아요" value="1" />좋아요
<option src="./imoticon/good.png" style="background-image:url(bad.png);width:23px;height:23px;" onclick="onClick2(this.value)" title="싫어요" value="-1" />싫어요
</select>
.....
```

And JS code is same as

```
 ...
     var q = document.getElementById("input1").value+"@@"+document.getElementById("txt1").value+"@@"+getCookie("username")+"@@"+document.getElementById("LikeHate").value;
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "inputComment.php?q=" +q, true);
   ...
```

And in PHP, after explode("@@",$q), last value will be an integer and sum up to data file.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest and best answer I think.

[image]

As a result of above selection.

[image]

Everyone wants the above result of the picture.

I pointed at the moon with my fingers, and I saw my fingers were wrong. We need a more inclusive posture for our future. I am grateful for the reproach of everyone.